# Add HTML tags to this regex string

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm using a tiny little JS plugin to truncate multiple lines of text on a site I'm working on.

The only problem is that the script is counting HTML tags `<a href="..."></a>` for example in the character count which is throwing things off a little.

This is how the script currently excludes characters;

```
regex = /[!-\/:-@\[-`{-~]$/
```

Which basically just strips out certain punctuation characters.

I've tried changing it to this;

```
regex = [!-\/:-@\[-`{-~]$<[^>]*>
```

But, not being too familiar with regex, it didn't seem to work.

If someone could nudge me in the right direction that would be great.

Answer (score 0):

In your initial regex you're looking for single characters that matches the tail of the string - either it be a character, word, line. Note the dollar sign '$'.

```
regex = /[!-\/:-@\[-`{-~]$/
```

Now you want to match anything between `<` and `>`.

```
regex = /[!-\/:-@\[-`{-~]$|<[^>]*$/
```

Note that you'll match: `<`, `<aaaa`, `<aaaa<` until the end of the string that you are matching against.

```
greedy_regex = /[!-\/:-@\[-`{-~]$|<[^>]*/
non_greedy_regex = /[!-\/:-@\[-`{-~]$|<[^>]*?/
```

If you remove the second '$' - `greedy_regex` - it will do a greedy match, matching `<b>c</b>` of `a<b>c</b>d`. Using the `?` as in `non_greedy_regex` it will match the '` only.